# Assign all child paths in the parent directory to an array

Tags: arrays, powershell, powershell-2.0, powershell-3.0

I am trying to assign all child paths of files in a directory to an array but not assigning the directories.

I am using the following command:

```
 $a = Get-ChildItem -path "C:\test\" -recurse | ?{!$_.PSIsContainer } | % { Write-Host $_.FullName }
```

The output is printed to the console and not saved in the variable.
Any idea way?

Answer (score 2):

The reason it is writing to the console is because you are saying [Write-Host](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh849877.aspx).  If you use [Write-Output](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh849921.aspx) instead, it will save to the variable.

```
$a = Get-ChildItem -path "C:\test\" -recurse | ?{!$_.PSIsContainer } | % { Write-Output $_.FullName }
```

Or try using the "[Select-Object](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh849895.aspx)" instead of write host.

It would look like this:

```
$a = Get-ChildItem -path "C:\test\" -recurse | ?{!$_.PSIsContainer } | select-object -expand FullName
```

Answer (score 0):

The console output from `Write-Host` is only displayed, not returned.

You will need to save the value in a variable first, then you can print it:

```
$a = Get-ChildItem -path "C:\test\" -recurse | ?{!$_.PSIsContainer };
$a | % { Write-Host $_.FullName }
```

Comment: Nope, still send the output to the console and to save it to the variable